# How to move the pictures in all subfolders to another new same folder in Python?

Tags: python, image

I plan to move the pictures in all subfolders (as shown in the picture) under the train file `train/LUAD` to another new folder `train_new/LUAD`. There are `.jpg` images in each subfolder such as the first one in the picture `TCGA-05-4249-01Z-00-DX1.9fce0297-cc19-4c04-872c-4466ee4024db`.

[image]

```
import os
import shutil

count = 0

def moveFiles(path, disdir): 
    
    dirlist = os.listdir(path)
    for i in dirlist:
        child = os.path.join('%s/%s' % (path, i))
        if os.path.isfile(child):
            
            imagename, jpg = os.path.splitext(i)    
            shutil.copy(child, os.path.join(disdir, imagename + ".jpg"))
            continue
        moveFiles(child, disdir)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rootimage = '/content/drive/MyDrive/stat841_final_data/train/LUAD'   
    disdir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/stat841_final_data/train_new/LUAD'       

    moveFiles(rootimage, disdir)
```

But it does not work. I only got image from the last subfolder except for other subfolders in my new folder `train_new/LUAD`...

Comment: Why are you calling `os.path.join` when you are joining the paths manually anyway?

Comment: Did you do some debugging work already? Is the `if` block ever entered?

Comment: Well then add some debug prints and report back on my questions.

Comment: Either the code has bugs or it already does what you want. Which one is it?

Comment: Then there's a bug in your code. Please refer to [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) resource and report back with debugging info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, you want to **move** (not copy) images from a nested file structure to a new folder, without nesting?

Be aware that this could overwrite images, if multiple images share the same name!

```
import pathlib

def move_files(source_folder:pathlib.Path, target_folder:pathlib.Path):
    target_folder.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    for image_file in source_folder.rglob("*.jpg"): # recursively find image paths
        image_file.rename(target_folder.joinpath(image_file.name))
```

If you are unsure maybe use the copy function first, so you won't lose your original data:

```
import pathlib
import shutil

def move_files(source_folder:pathlib.Path, target_folder:pathlib.Path):
    target_folder.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    for image_file in source_folder.rglob("*.jpg"): # recursively find image paths
        shutil.copy(image_file, target_folder.joinpath(image_file.name))
```